# CamelBlueprintTesting, why can't I override this propertyplaceholder?

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I have a boolean flag propertyplaceholder that I'm trying to override in one of my unit tests but it's not working.

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="id" persistent-id="persistent-id>
  <cm:default-properties>
    <cm:property name="flag" value="true" />
  </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

This flag gets use in a bean:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.myBean">
  <property name="flag" value="${flag}" />
</bean>
```

I'd like to override the property to be false when doing unit testing so I implemented the useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent() method:

```
@Override
protected Properties useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent() {
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.put("errorQueue", "mock:error");
  prop.put("flag", false);

  return prop;
```

}

My errorQueue property is working fine and error messages are going to "mock:error" but the flag isn't overridden property. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do those overrides when its `<bean>`s

eg the following `${flag}` is 100% controlled by OSGi blueprint:

`<bean id="myBean" class="com.myBean">
  <property name="flag" value="${flag}" />
</bean>`

And the `useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent` is for the Camel properties component for Camel property placeholders, eg the `{{ }}` syntax that Camel uses.

http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that. Thanks for pointing that out. I switched over to using "useOverridePropertiesWithConfigAdmin" and got the flag to work properly. Thanks Claus!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that your value is not accepted.
Javadoc for [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) states:

> The *Properties* class represents a persistent set of properties. The Properties can be saved to a stream or loaded from a stream. Each key and its corresponding value in the property list is a **string**.

You are using a boolean, try with

```
prop.put("flag", "false");
```

In general key-values for `property-placeholder` are strings and converted to the appropriate type at runtime.